# getting value using xpath, ruby

Tags: xpath, jruby

I need to get value 9,70 from the following code, but am unable to do so. The number's comma is part of number and not delimiter, so the whole number is needed in one string. `id="cheapest wine"` is unique, but it keeps returning error.

```
<tr class="chartTableHeader">
<tr class="chartTableRow">
  <td class="chartTableColFirst" style="height: 19px">
  <td class="chartTableCol" style="height: 19px">
  <td class="chartTableCol" style="height: 19px">
  <span id="cheapest wine">9,70</span>
  </td>
  <td class="chartTableCol" style="height: 19px">
  <td class="chartTableCol" style="height: 19px">
  <td class="chartTableCol" style="height: 19px">
```

Comment: Your code is not showing, please fix the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using Nokogiri, and assuming that your html is formatted properly, you can get the value as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<-EOF
<root>
<span id="cheapest wine">9,70</span>
</root>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.xpath('//span[@id="cheapest wine"]').map do |add|
  puts add.inner_text
end
```

Here the key is the XPath query: `//span[@id="cheapest wine"]` which searches for the `span` nodes whose `id` is `"cheapest wine"` (being an id, there should only be one).

Comment: `//span[@id='cheapest wine']` would be enough. Then use the correct DOM method to get the **string value**: selecting text nodes in a **mixed content** data model it's not the best idea... Or just get the string value atomic type evaluating `string(//span[@id='cheapest wine'])` if your XPath engine support this general XPath expressions.

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks a mil for these precisions, I have amended my answer to follow your recommendations.  Hopefully this is ok now?

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following XPath expression**:

```
number(
    translate(tr[@class='chartTableRow']/td/span[@id='cheapest wine'], 
             ',', 
             '.'
             )
      )
```

where the current node from which the XPath expression is evaluated is the parent of the XML fragment shown in your question.

**The XPath expression above evaluates to `9.7`**